# no item named False error when filtering DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to subset a dataframe using an in operator. In the 'data' column, some of the strings contain the text I am looking for 'Go'. However, this is the error I get:

```
In: subset = df['Go' in df.data]
Out: KeyError: u'no item named False'
```

Can anyone help with this? I have also tried it with parentheses around the boolean statement.

Comment: 'Go' in df.data is obviously returning False so you are basically trying to access using `df[False]`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`str.contains` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern) to test if `Go` is in each string in the `data` column -- it returns a boolean array which can then be used to select rows of `df`:

```
df.loc[df['data'].str.contains(r'Go')]
```

For example,

```
In [74]: df = pd.DataFrame({'data': ['No', 'Go', 'BoGo']})

In [75]: df['data'].str.contains(r'Go')
Out[75]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: data, dtype: bool

In [76]: df.loc[df['data'].str.contains(r'Go')]
Out[76]: 
   data
1    Go
2  BoGo
```

---

`'Go' in df['data']` is testing if `Go` is in the index of `df['data']` and is returning a single boolean value, False. `df[False]` is raising a KeyError because there is no column named `False`.